# Pandas indexed Series Subset (of a DataFrame) not changing values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following table:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(({'code':['A121','A121','A121','H812','H812','H812','Z198','Z198','Z198','S222','S222','S222'],
                        'mode':['stk','sup','cons','stk','sup','cons','stk','sup','cons','stk','sup','cons'],
                        datetime.date(year=2021,month=5,day=1):[4,2,np.nan,2,2,np.nan,6,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan],
                        datetime.date(year=2021,month=5,day=2):[1,np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                        datetime.date(year=2021,month=5,day=3):[12,5,np.nan,13,5,np.nan,12,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,5,np.nan],
                        datetime.date(year=2021,month=5,day=4):[np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,4,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,7,np.nan]}))
df = df.set_index('mode')
```

[image]

---

I want to achieve the following, I want the the rows wherever `cons` to be set according to some arithemetic calculations:

`cons` for the corresponding date and code needs to be set to the following calculation `prev_date stk - current_date stk + sup`

I have tried the code below:

```
dates = list(df.columns)
dates.remove('code')
for date in dates:
    prev_date = date - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    if(df.loc["stk"].get(prev_date,None) is not None):
        opn_stk = df.loc["stk",prev_date].reset_index(drop=True)
        cls_stk = df.loc["stk",date].reset_index(drop=True)
        sup = df.loc["sup",date].fillna(0).reset_index(drop=True)
        cons = opn_stk - cls_stk + sup
        df.loc["cons",date] = cons
```

I do not receive any error, **however the `cons` values does not change at all**.

I suspect this is probably because `df.loc["cons",date]` is an indexed Series and the calculation `opn_stk - cls_stk + sup` is an unindexed Series.
Any idea how to fix this?

P.S Also I am using loops to calculate this, is there any other vectorized way that would be more efficient

---

Expected Output

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although @Henry Ecker's answer is very elegant, it is very slow compared to what I have done (over 10x slower), so I would like to go ahead with my implementation fixed

My implementation fixed as per Henry Ecker's suggestion `df.loc["cons",date] = cons.to_numpy()`

```
dates = list(df.columns)
dates.remove('code')
for date in dates:
    prev_date = date - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    if(df.loc["stk"].get(prev_date,None) is not None):
        opn_stk = df.loc["stk",prev_date].reset_index(drop=True)    # gets the stock of prev date
        cls_stk = df.loc["stk",date].reset_index(drop=True)         # gets the stock of current date
        sup = df.loc["sup",date].fillna(0).reset_index(drop=True)   # gets suplly of current date
        cons = opn_stk - cls_stk + sup
        df.loc["cons",date] = cons.to_numpy()
```

Just as a sidenote:
My implementation runs on the full data (not this, I created this as a toy example) in `0:00:00.053309 seconds` and Henry Ecker's implementation run in `0:00:00.568888 seconds` so more than **10x slower**.

This is probably because he is iterating over the codes whereas I am iterating over dates. At any given point of time I will have at most 30 dates, but there can be more that 500 codes

Answer (score 1):

Let's try a groupby apply instead:

```py
def calc_cons(g):
    # Transpose
    t = g[g.columns[g.columns != 'code']].T
    # Update Cons
    g.loc[g.index == 'cons', g.columns != 'code'] = (-t['stk'].diff() +
                                                     t['sup'].fillna(0)).to_numpy()
    return g


df = df.groupby('code', as_index=False, sort=False).apply(calc_cons)
# print(df[df.index == 'cons'])
print(df)
```

```
      code  2021-05-01  2021-05-02  2021-05-03  2021-05-04
mode                                                      
stk   A121         4.0         1.0        12.0         NaN
sup   A121         2.0         NaN         5.0         1.0
cons  A121         NaN         3.0        -6.0         NaN
stk   H812         2.0         3.0        13.0         NaN
sup   H812         2.0         NaN         5.0         4.0
cons  H812         NaN        -1.0        -5.0         NaN
stk   Z198         6.0         2.0        12.0         NaN
sup   Z198         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
cons  Z198         NaN         4.0       -10.0         NaN
stk   S222         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
sup   S222         2.0         NaN         5.0         7.0
cons  S222         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

---

*Assumes columns are in sorted order by date in 1 day intervals.

Comment: the ```cons``` for first column should be np.nan

Comment: Added the expected output. Your output seems to be incorrect for the second last ```cons```. I think that can be fixed by not doing ```fillna(0)``` for stk

Comment: Updated to reflect the new information. See how that works.

Comment: thanks so much, this definitely works and is a better implementation. However could you shed some insight on the reason for what I did not working

Comment: I'm not 100% sure because I can't fully follow your logic, but it's likely to do with the fact that you create 3 dataframes and do computation on them then try to put it into a row of the existing frame. You might try `df.loc["cons",date] = cons.to_numpy()` and see if some values come over.

Comment: yes doing ```df.loc["cons",date] = cons.to_numpy()``` worked